# Conditionally construct schema depending on database version in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Assume the following table and custom range type:

```
create table booking (
     identifier      integer                not null primary key,
     room            uuid                   not null,
     start_time      time without time zone not null,
     end_time        time without time zone not null
);

create type timerange as range (subtype = time);
```

In PostgreSQL v10, you can do:

```
alter table booking add constraint overlapping_times
exclude using gist
(
     room with =,
     timerange(start_time, end_time) with &&
);
```

In PostgreSQL v9.5/v9.6, you have to manually cast the `uuid` column as `gist_btree` does not support `uuid`:

```
alter table booking add constraint overlapping_times
exclude using gist
(
     (room::text) with =,
     timerange(start_time, end_time) with &&
);
```

I would like to support v9.5, v9.6 and v10 for my customers. Is there a way to conditionally add the above constraint in the same .sql file, depending on the version of the current database?

Comment: If you already have a shell script for installation, you could do some shell-magic and create the correct (sym)link to the corresponding .sql file(s) and include these in a generic .sql *master* script. The point is that failing to detect the version would fail. (which is probably what you want)

Comment: @wildplasser Interesting idea. I could have all common SQL scripts in /common and then have a /v9.5, /v9.5, /v10, ... directory. I'll experiment with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [dynamic sql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ecpg-dynamic.html)

For example:

```
do
$block$
declare
  l_version text;
begin
  select setting into l_version from pg_settings where name = 'server_version';

  execute 
    format(
      $script$
        alter table booking add constraint overlapping_times
        exclude using gist
        (
          %s with =,
          timerange(start_time, end_time) with &&
        )
      $script$,
      case when (l_version like '9.5.%' or l_version like '9.6.%') then '(room::text)' else 'room' end
    )
  ;
end;
$block$
  language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Cool idea, very useful!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof of concept:

---

```
#!/bin/sh

#THE_HOST="192.168.0.104"
THE_HOST="192.168.0.101"

get_version ()
{
psql -t -h ${THE_HOST} -U postgres postgres <<OMG | awk -e '{ print $2; }'
select version();
OMG
}

# ############################################################################
#       main
#
# - Connect to database to retrieve version
# - use the retrieved version to create a symlink "versioned" to
#   one of our subdirs 
# - call an sql script that includes this symlink/some.sql
# symlinking to a non-existing directory will cause a dead link
# (, and the script to fail.)
# ergo: there should be a subdir "verX.Y.Z" for every supported version X.Y.Z
# ############################################################################

pg_version=`get_version`
#echo "version=${pg_version}"

rm versioned
ln -fs "ver${pg_version}" versioned

if [ -f versioned/alter.sql ]; then
        echo created link versioned to "ver${pg_version}"
else
 echo "version ${pg_version} not supported today..."
 echo "Failed!"
 exit 1
fi

psql -t -h ${THE_HOST} -U postgres postgres <<LETS_GO

\i common/create.sql

\i versioned/alter.sql

\echo done!
LETS_GO


#eof
```

Comment: I am going to experiment with this this week, thanks!